# str data from "file1.txt" do not compare to str data from "file2.txt" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I exported 2 excel .XLSX to a 2 differents txt files in ANSI encoding.
Then I made a code that extracts the data (mails) so I can compare the two files (like a assistance checker), if the files have  str equals values, print it and count it.

The problem is that even if I verify that both lists have equals values, when I try to compare, seems to look like there is not equals value

I'm new at programing in general and with python

Sorry for my english, my mother tongue is spanish

For the moment I assume that in order of my lack of knowledge I'm having troubles with the .txt files, but i do not know how to solve it

```
master9b=open("2020 LISTA MASTER B.txt",encoding="ANSI")
asistencias=open("Asistencia 20_08_2020(1-75).txt",encoding="ANSI")
m=list()
a=list()
listb=list()
con=0
listasi=list()
for listasi in asistencias:
    if "@domain" in listasi:
        listasi=listasi.strip().split()
        m = m + listasi[5:6] #at this position are the mails

#if I print m here, shows me all the mails that marked assistance 

for listb in master9b:
    if "@domain" in listb:
        listb=listb.strip().split()
        a = a + listb[2:3] #the mails are at that position

#if I print a here, shows me all the mails of the group

print("Asistencia 9B")
while True:
    if a[con] in m:
        print(a[con])
        con=con+1
    else:
        break
print("Total de asistentes del 9B:", con)

#in that while is the problem
```

Comment: post the sample input and expected output

Comment: The problem is that your while loop is exiting as soon as it encounters a mail that doesn’t match.

Comment: @Jon thanks sir, I saw the mistake